# What are possible defences against Frey effect?

Tags: microwave

"Frey Effect" is named after Dr. Allan H. Frey, an American neuroscientist, who first published information about microwaves causing humans to hear sounds, including clicks, voices, etc. Frey Effect is also referred to as Microwave Auditory Effect or Microwave Hearing Effect.

There are many articles, scholarly publications on the Internet, from army scientists and others who have conducted research into this. You can search WikiPedia for more information. Some links mention that this can be used to transmit both audible and inaudible messages, in case of inaudible message, it is the same hypnosis to program(brain wash) a person, and the person cannot put a conscious defense against it.

What microwave frequencies can this Frey Effect use? Can these frequencies travel through concrete walls or an average house? What possible defense can a person put in place to neutralize someone from utilizing Frey Effect to attack them?

Comment: *There are many articles, scholarly publications on the Internet, from army scientists and others who have conducted research into this.* if you say this in your question then why ask *What microwave frequencies can this Frey Effect use*?

Comment: I hear tin foil is an effective barrier. You can use it to make hats.

Comment: @Andyaka I haven't read them all. How would I know how to block those frequencies?

Comment: The very 1st hit (wiki) tells you what frequencies have been used. Knowing those frequencies it's not rocket science to do a bit of research on how to block those EM waves.

Comment: Vote to close as this question is off topic here.

Comment: @Andyaka That is just one frequency mentioned in WikiPedia, there are many other frequencies mentioned in others. So I'm not sure if it utilizes one frequency or many others.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Why is this off-topic? Doesn't it concern electrical engineering? Doesn't it deal with phenomena studied by electrical engineering?

Comment: I could loan you my [hat with the built in RF detector.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/1-hatband)  I'm pretty sure that any RF signal powerful enough to make your head go "snap, crackle, and pop" would light up my hat like a Christmas tree.

Comment: Note: Even though this questions sounds a lot like pseudoscience, [Wikipedia thinks it's a real effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_auditory_effect), though it probably doesn't do whatever the pseudoscientists think it does.

Comment: As it is, the question is still pretty broad and should therefore be off-topic. You could ask which frequencies cause the Frey effect, but that's biology not electronics. When you know the frequency, you could ask how well it's attenuated by concrete, or how to reflect it - that's [on-topic here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @user253751 - Please do realize that content on Wikipedia is crowd sourced. Anyone can signup to add and edit content including those with ideas that are less than mainstream.

Comment: @MichaelKaras You would be surprised by how accurate it generally is. Or are you a high school teacher? Notice the page says two main things: 1) there is an effect. 2) pseudoscientists sometimes refer to it when it is not actually happening. I do not see anything unbelievable about these claims. In fact that follows a pattern commonly seen in pseudoscience, where they start from something real but uncommon, and then claim it's being used to harass them everywhere.

Comment: @user253751 - I am not intending to refer specifically to the linked site but rather in general that one needs to consider the source when referencing Wikipedia. In large part Wikipedia is a very useful resource and I even donate a nice amount to them each year to help fund their efforts.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I am not citing equations or anything from Wikipedia, for such a fringe topic. But the fact that Wikipedia says it's a real effect, and notes the connection to pseudoscience, should be enough of an indication that maybe the effect is real and not just pseudoscience, in which case it is possible to write non-pseudoscientific questions about the effect.

Comment: I don't doubt that the effect is real.  I doubt that there's any need of defending against it.  The fear that the effect is being used for nefarious purposes on a scale that would require a defense is paranoid - and that's what has everyone making tinfoil hat jokes and voting to close the question.

Comment: To put this in perspective:  Wikipedia says the Frey effect occurs at power levels of 80 milliwatts per square centimeter and above.  That's 800 watts per square meter, which is fairly close to the power of sunlight per square meter (around 1000 watts per square meter.)  That's either a mighty powerful microwave transmitter, or one more hell of a high gain antenna concentrating a lower power on a small spot.

Comment: "... in 1961. In his experiments, the subjects were discovered to be able to hear appropriately pulsed microwave radiation, from a distance of 100 meters from the transmitter. This was accompanied by side effects such as dizziness, headaches, and a pins and needles sensation."  These are same symptoms of nuclear radiation sickness and higher levels caused American Tank Pilots to pass out when the early Radar was located too close to the pilot's head and he would pass out.   For ULV <` 1kHz it takes about 2 Tesla to activate your AXON impulses to muscles next to your skin  . Huge.

Comment: But magnetic Tesla Styms are very popular in EU from Slovania with 4T 300 Hz BW ~ 30pulse/s Magnetic Pulses for Nerve damage repairs in Therapeutic treatment centres.  Pins & needles sensation is an electrical problem with nerve sensor axons that fire without sensor activation at the extremity but along the pathway from damage.

Answer (score 6):

The Frey Effect gives every indication of being an extremely blunt instrument indeed. While it is entirely plausible that electromagnetic energy of a suitable level may cause some form of auditory effects, the prospect of it being used in a finely controlled and targeted way is almost zero. Projects seeking to utilise this effect have not met with success as far as can be established publicly.

In situations where such effects have been demonstrated to exist, the effect is believed by some sources to be by "thermoelastic expansion of portions of the auditory apparatus." As above, that's an extremely blunt axe indeed to do anything covert or useful with.

It is likely that RF (Radio Frequency) energy of almost any wavelength is able to provide thermo-acoustic effects at sufficient power levels in some circumstances. As noted in the wikipedia reference, the power levels required are liable to cause overheating before they provide communications ability. Screening from RF can be achieved by use of electromagnetic shielding - the standard "joke" tinfoil hat is not a good choice as it will tend to provide some capacitive shielding but little magnetic shielding.  The helmet from a suit of armour would probably work. Really! Hardly a practical solution to a problem which has about zero chance of being a real world one.

This wikipedia article [Microwave auditory effect](https://wiki2.org/en/Microwave_auditory_effect) provides a good amount of information and many references.

While I am unlikely to be popular for suggesting it, I very strongly suggest that you carefully consider the following passage from that wikipedia article before investing much time in the subject.

**___________________________________________**

"Numerous individuals suffering from auditory hallucinations, delusional disorders, or other mental illnesses have claimed that government agents use forms of mind control technologies based on microwave signals to transmit sounds and thoughts into their heads as a form of electronic harassment, referring to the alleged technology as "voice to skull" or "V2K".

There are extensive online support networks and numerous websites maintained by people fearing mind control. California psychiatrist Alan Drucker has identified evidence of delusional disorders on many of these websites and other psychologists are divided over whether such sites reinforce mental troubles, or act as a form of group social support.

Psychologists have identified many examples of people reporting 'mind control experiences' (MCEs) on self-published web pages that are "highly likely to be influenced by delusional beliefs". Common themes include "Bad Guys" using "psychotronics" and "microwaves", frequent mention of the CIA's MKULTRA project, and frequent citing of a scientific paper entitled "Human auditory system response to modulated electromagnetic energy"."

Comment: Had a conversation with a such a person once, on the same topic. Everything I suggested, he claimed would not work. "They" would always find him, even if he was in a cave in China! "They" would use satellites beaming "scalar waves" into his head. Basically, the tech he was claiming existed is magic. The real test if if the voices go away when you take anti-psychotic drugs

Comment: @DirkBruere At least one Chinese leader grew up in a cave house in China - and was proud to recount the fact. Such dwellings are used in a number of locations where the local geology allows and I've seen a few from a distance in passing. I've also seen similar in Italy, also, sadly, on the fly. Suitability for protection from EM neural modulation effects or EMP unknown to me.

Comment: @DirkBruere Indian caves. [That's me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXnOY.jpg), but I didn't note any reduction in EM effects.

Comment: I also got into a conversation with someone who was allegedly being subjected to the usual Mind Kontrol stuff, as well as being followerd 24/7 by teams of agents from MI5. I costed out such an operation and wondered why a nobody like him would warrant several million a year being spent for no good reason.